# Datepicker automatically hide on month or year select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can go back from date to year in datepicker. But when I try to come back to date, when i clicked on year, datepicker automatically hide.

```
 var datePickerOptions = this.data || {}; 
    datePickerOptions.format = datePickerOptions.format || "mm-dd-yyyy";
    datePickerOptions.language = datePickerOptions.language || this.lang.code; 
    var $context = this;
    var dateContainer = this.container.find(".datepicker");
    dateContainer.datepicker(datePickerOptions).on('changeDate', function (ev) { 
    // here i'm getting the value 
    });
```

Comment: can you provide a fiddler?

Comment: What datepicker plugin are you talking about? Provide some code.

Comment: fiddle fiddle fiddle please!!! you expect us to solve your problem without seeing the code?

Comment: please edit your question and add the code there!

Comment: I'm talking about gridMvc.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
This because of bootstrap-datepicker.js .
on click event you can find like following.

case 'span':
                        if (!target.is('.disabled')) {
                            this.viewDate.setUTCDate(1);
                            if (target.is('.month')) {
                                var day = 1;
                                var month = target.parent().find('span').index(target);
                                var year = this.viewDate.getUTCFullYear();
                                this.viewDate.setUTCMonth(month);
                                this._trigger('changeMonth', this.viewDate);
                                if (this.o.minViewMode === 1) {
                                    this._setDate(UTCDate(year, month, day,0,0,0,0));
                                }
                            } else {
                                var year = parseInt(target.text(), 10)||0;
                                var day = 1;
                                var month = 0;
                                this.viewDate.setUTCFullYear(year);
                                this._trigger('changeYear', this.viewDate);
                                if (this.o.minViewMode === 2) {
                                    this._setDate(UTCDate(year, month, day,0,0,0,0));
                                }
                            }
                            this.showMode(-1);
                            this.fill();
                        }
```

instead of `this.fill()`, if you use like following code, this will work as you expected.

```
if (target.is('.month')) {


     if (!this._o.changeMonth) {
                                        this.fill();
                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    if (!this._o.changeYear) {
                                        this.fill();
                                    }
                                }
```

I hope, this will help you. :-)